# Запись данных, введенных пользователем в поле ACF

Tags: wordpress, acf

Здравствуйте. На сайте Wordpress есть дополнительное поле (плагин Advanced Custom Fields), в которое пользователь вводит число и нажимает кнопку Отправить.

Цель: переписать существующие данные по-умолчанию на то число, что ввел пользователь и вывести его на экране.

Есть скрипт по захвату данных из поля ввода, но как потом записать в поле ACF я не понимаю.

```
<input type="text" name="" id="bTC" placeholder="Например, 10000">
<input type="button" value="Заказать" id="otpravit" onclick="someFunc();">
<script>
  function someFunc(){
     var transfer = document.getElementById("bTC").value;
     var price = transfer;
     var div = document.createElement("div");
     div.innerHTML = price;
     document.getElementById("Per").appendChild(div);
     return false;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Вам нужно выучить, что такое ajax. Хорошая документация на русском здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Мне бы для начала просто понять как перезаписать данные в поле, можно даже после обновления страниц и как прикрутить функцию update_field() ко всему этому.

Comment: К этому - никак. Потому что у вас тут код js в браузере, а обновление поля в базе через функцию update_filed() - это код php на сервере.

Comment: Можете дать направление в котором двигаться? Можно ли сделать получение данных с пользователя php методами, а не скриптом?

Comment: Можно. Делайте форму ввода, обрабатывайте её в php на сервере.

Comment: Спасибо за верное направление)